# Default merge target for "closed as exact duplicate" questions

Tags: feature-request, moderator-abilities, merged-questions

Virtually every question merge is on a question that's already been closed as an exact duplicate, into that same duplicate question. When merging a question that's closed as an exact duplicate, is it possible to make the master question ID default to the ID of the duplicate?