# Automatically populate merge URL when closed as dupe

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default merge target for “closed as exact duplicate” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86796/default-merge-target-for-closed-as-exact-duplicate-questions)

Its a small thing, but why not pre-populate the Master Question URL when the question-to-be-merged has been closed as a duplicate?

[image]

Terms here are a little sketchy, so let me be clear.  When considering a merge, we have two questions

- The master question
- The question to be merged into the master, or the duplicate question

In order to merge the duplicate into the master, a moderator must (if it is not already) first close the duplicate question.  A question cannot be merged before it is first closed.  Now, because it is a duplicate, the question is often closed *as a duplicate* of the master question.  At this point, we know into what question the dupe will be merged.

So why not just pre-populate the master question URL in the merge form when the question has been closed as dupe?

Comment: From now on I'm just going to send my feature requests to you and have you post them, so they'll get more upvotes

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Dude, narwhals.